# Which is the best approach - Proxying the API request to another server (or) by using the URL directly?

Tags: angular, rest, api

In Angular, I learnt that we can proxy the API request or we can use the URL directly without using any proxy configurations. The two approaches that I've learnt are:

> **With Proxy:**

***proxy.config.json***

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

***package.json:***

edit "start" of your package.jsson

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

> **Without Proxy:**

Consider any service file to make REST API calls:

***user.service.ts***

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

public API = 'http://localhost:8080';
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.API + '/users');
  }

}
```

So, which of these methods are the correct method of approaching? 
How do we use this in a production type of environment?
If there are any other such alternatives, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That proxy only works in development mode which is opened by `ng serve`. For production mode, you need to do the same job with Nginx, Apache or any other web server application which serves a Angular project.

If you request XHR call directly, you should deal with CORS issue. So I recommend former one.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is Nginx, Apache are?

Comment: What kind of CORS issue I should deal with if I call XHR directly?

Comment: After run `ng build` to get a production build, you need something to serve it. and that thing could be https://nginx.org/, https://httpd.apache.org/. `ng serve` is do the 
same thing with Node.js that those web servers do but only for development purpose.

Comment: @AshfaqueRifaye For security reasons, browsers allow only request from same origin. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS Here's more detail :)

Comment: Okay that served much purpose.

Comment: I wanted to learn how Apache/Nginx works in a Development environment. I am using my laptop to learn how these works and how can I configure my project as same as a production code. Is it possible to learn them practically with my personal laptop?